# Sink overflow hole is "leaking" rust

Tags: sink, rust-removal

The overflow hole on my bathroom sink is rusting and will tend to "leak" brown rust particles into the basin when water is splashed up into the hole. Is there an easy fix here?

[image]

Comment: does water flow freely through the overflow or is it clogged?

Comment: Is the basin steel or china?

Comment: It's china, @Jasen. And I it's clogged!

Comment: you could dry a drain plunger on the overflow, if that doesn't work you're probably going to have to diassemble the plug-hole and trap.

Comment: It looks like a cast iron sink. There is a white porcelain paint that you could put on the edge to clean it up. But first you have to solve the reason water is coming out of that hole, under normal usage it should remain dry. Its purpose is to prevent the sink from overflowing its walls flooding the room.